# How do you access a vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to get the hang of smart pointers. I have a vector of unique_ptr to double array which I am able to create, but can't access it.

```
vector<unique_ptr<double[]>> arrDoubles;

//...

unique_ptr<double[]>dataArr(new double[size]);
arrDoubles.push_back(move(dataArr));
```

Now,

```
auto datAr = arrDoubles[0];
```

gives the following :

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>&) [with _Tp = double; _Dp = std::default_delete<double []>]’
```

Comment: Because `auto datAr = arrDoubles[0];` attempts to copy-construct a `unique_ptr`, and, as you know, `std::unique_ptr` does not have copy constructors.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to create a copy of a `unique_ptr` which can't be done. Use a reference.

```
auto& datAr = arrDoubles[0];
```